# Angular - How to separately add loader to a ng-select dropdown list that is taking a very long time to load

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

In my Angular-15 application, I have a ng-select dropdown that is taking a very long time because the data is massive.

**component.ts:**

```
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/features/admin/services/employee.service';

export class EmployeeCreateComponent {

  employeesDatas: any[] = [];
  createEmployeeForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  }

  constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {;
    this.loadAllEmployees();
  }

  createEmployee() {
    this.createEmployeeForm = this.fb.group({
      employeeCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  this.loadAllEmployees(){
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesDropdown().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.employeeesDatas = res.data;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I am loading all the employees from the backend into the ng-select dropdown.

**component.html**

```
<form
  class="form-horizontal"
  id="add-form"
  [formGroup]="createEmployeeForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onEmployeeSubmitForm()"
>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Employee"
    >Employee:</label
  >
  <ng-select
    [items]="employeesDatas"
    [selectOnTab]="true"
    [searchable]="true"
    bindValue="EmployeeCode"
    bindLabel="EmployeeName"
    placeholder="Select Employee"
    [multiple]="false"
    [clearable]="true"
    required
    formControlName="employeeCode"
  >
  </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>

    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-success"
      [disabled]="isLoading"
      (click)="createValidate()"
    >
      <span
        *ngIf="isLoading"
        class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"
      ></span>
      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

**Finally I have the service.ts:**

```
  getEmployeesDropdown(): Observable<IEmployeeListDropdown[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployeeListDropdown[]>(
      this.baseUrl + '/employes/all-employees-list'
    );
  }
```

What I observed is that since I'm loading all the employees, when I click on the ng-select dropdown it takes a long time for it to respond because the employee record is very large.

How do I put a loader when the ng-select dropdown is clicked or what else can I do in order not to keep the users waiting too long?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you're referring to the response time after the data has been loaded or while it has been loaded.
If it is about after the data has been loaded, you can try virtualizing the select by using the ng-select property `virtualScroll`: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/virtual-scroll

Comment: I think is a bad approach to load a huge number of users into it. Maybe you should start loading them when they want to type and the search request on the server side should be triggered if at least 3 chars where typed or so. Check this article https://medium.com/@sangumallikharjuna/ng-select-typeahead-with-debouncetime-to-fetch-server-response-79dc32fa72a4

Comment: Or you may look for [`[isLoading]`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) attribute. When loading the data, set it to false, once the Observable is returned, set to true.